# Logging output in nginx

Tags: nginx, lua

Im new to Nginx and Lua -

I have been trying to do a simple logging of a variable in a Lua script inside a nginx.conf file but I cannot see the output.

Im using the ngx.log inside a content_by_lua 
Inside the conf file

```
location /test {
      content_by_lua '
      ngx.log(ngx.STDERR, "Usage variable " .. ngx.var.usage);
      ';
    }
```

On using curl to ping my localhost, I see no output (on the server, response or the error log file)

Where can I see this output?
Thanks for any help in this matter

Answer (score 0):

I think the log level `STDERR` is deprecated in nginx. Try to use `ngx.log(ngx.ERR, ...` instead, and the log should be in the error log file.

Comment: I tried this out, but there is still no logging in the error log file.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. The nginx conf file was edited and it was logging these errors at a different place.

Redirected the error output to the current working directory and can see the log outputs.